# State pension and gifting property in the uk

Tags: united-kingdom

As I understand it,when you live in the UK,when you gift property to a child and still live in the property they must charge the going rental for your area.If your total pension including state pension is less than this does this mean that you are effectively excluded from this

Answer (score 4):

You could gift it and then your child could permit you to live in it rent free.  But then the property will still be considered to be in your estate for inheritance tax purposes when the time comes... that's because it wouldn't actually have been a gift but a "gift with reservation of benefit", so far as HMRC are concerned.

This article might be useful: https://www.thetimes.co.uk/money-mentor/article/gifting-property-tax-implications/

It's a complex area - consider taking professional advice; there may be other ways of achieving whatever you're trying to do.  But be aware there are some pretty dubious schemes being touted out there: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-39589083 for example.